# Letter guessing game Java

Tags: java, char

I have been working on a java guessing game for letters (a-z)! However i have created the game perfectly by using the number 1-26, but i cannot figure out how to convert each integer to a letter ie a = 1, b = 2,....z = 26!

I want the user to try and guess the letter and not the number, but i cannot workout how to do this!

(I know how to generate a random character but i cant implement and link it to each integer within the game correctly)

```
Random r = new Random();

char targetLetter = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! And i can display my code if it is needed

```
public class Stack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random(); //This is were the computer selects the Target

        int guess;
        int numGuesses = 0;
        int Target;
        String userName;
        String playagain;
        boolean play = true;
        int session = 0;
        int sessions = 0;
        int bestScore = 0;

        Scanner consoleIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello! Please enter your name:\n"); //This is were the user enters his/her name
        userName = name.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Hello " + userName + " :) Welcome to the game!\n");


        while (play = true) {
            session++;
            Target = rand.nextInt(26) + 1;
            System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 26? You will have 5 attempts to guess the correct number"); //This is where the computer asks the user to guess the number and how many guesses they will have

            do {
                guess = consoleIn.nextInt();
                numGuesses++;

                if (guess > 26)
                    System.out.println("Error! Above MAXIMUM range");
                else if (guess <= 0)
                    System.out.println("Error! Below MINIMUM range");
                else if (guess > Target)
                    System.out.println("Sorry! Your guess was too high! :)"); //This is to help the player get to the answer
                else if (guess < Target)
                    System.out.println("Sorry! Your guess was too low! :)"); //This is to help the player get to the answer
            } while (guess != Target && numGuesses < 5);

            if (guess == Target) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations " + userName + ", it took you " + numGuesses + " attempts to guess correctly!"); //This tells the player that they got the correct answer and how many attempts it took
                sessions++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry " + userName + ", You've used up all of your guesses! The correct answer was " + Target + "!");  //This tells the player that they failed to find the number and then tells them what the correct answer
            }
            {
                Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Would you like another GO " + userName + "? [Y/N]");//This asks the player if they would like to play again
                playagain = answer.nextLine();
                if (playagain.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {//This is what happens if the player opts to play again
                    play = true;
                    numGuesses = 0;
                } else if (playagain.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {//This is what happens if the player opts to exit the game
                    play = false;
                    System.out.println("Thanks for playing " + userName + "! :) Please come back soon!");
                    System.out.println("You had  " + session + " Goes");
                    System.out.println("The number of times you guessed correctly: " + sessions + "");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code of above?

Comment: Display your code.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! Which method would best suit my given code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);      
            System.out.println("Guess the Letter");
            String myLetter=scan.nextLine();
                //get the letter of myLetter variable then convert to Uppercase
            char enteredLetter=Character.toUpperCase(myLetter.charAt(0));
                    //26 only because the characters array starts with index 0
            char[] characters ={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
                    //I had created a parrallel array symbolizing int value of each letter
            int[] range={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26};
            //this variable convert user input to one of the array element of range
            int userInputToInt=0;
            //this variable is for knowing what int[] range array element must the value of userInputToInt fall
            int userInputControlLoop=0;
            char randomLetter=characters[(int)(Math.random()*26)];
            // get the random input of computer convert it to int
            int computerInputToInt=0;

                //this loop is for getting the int value of randomLetter input by the computer
                for(int i=0;i<characters.length;++i)
                {
                    if(randomLetter==characters[i])
                    {

                        computerInputToInt=range[i];
                    }
                }
                //this loop is for getting the int value of user inputted letter
                for(char i:characters)
                {
                    if(enteredLetter==i)
                    {
                        userInputToInt=range[userInputControlLoop];
                    }
                    ++userInputControlLoop;
                }


                 //test the entered letter of user
            if(enteredLetter==randomLetter)
            {
                System.out.println("Correct Guess");
                System.out.println("The letter is:"+randomLetter);
            }
            //test the entered letter of user if greater than computer input
            else if(userInputToInt>computerInputToInt)
            {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Guess");
                System.out.println("The letter is too high");
                System.out.println("The letter is:"+randomLetter);
            }
            //test the entered letter of user if lesser than computer input
            else if(userInputToInt<computerInputToInt)
            {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Guess");
                System.out.println("The letter is too low");
                System.out.println("The letter is:"+randomLetter);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..using a snippet of the code i am able to generate a random letter yes however it is saying there is an erroring compiling the code! But when i run it anyway it works?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry i had an extra class in the background causing the error! Thanks for answer! Really helped

Comment: I change my answer I read the Math.random() I change the 25 to 26

Comment: if this help you, you can accept this as an answer for future reference of other people

Comment: Would this method allow for...If the user entered 'A'  but the random letter was 'D' that it would provide feedback to the user telling them they where to low?

Comment: @Slynch771 I had edit my answer for you to know how to enter if too low or too high please see my comments in each of my code good luck and happy coding :) sorry for late reply I'm just got home from school

Answer (score 1):

use arrays of characters

```
char[] chars = ['A','B','C'...];
```

and use the random numbers to map to each character

```
char targetLetter = chars[r.nextInt(26)];
```

Comment: Awww yes! So would this also allow the user to enter a letter when asked to guess aswell?

Comment: Update this is not working,  The array wont work it says 'String cannot be converted to char

Answer (score 0):

Use the same method that you do for your random characters. Assuming you have your guessed character as an int variable called "guess", and it has value 1-26 corresponding A-Z:

```
Random r = new Random();
char targetLetter = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');

...

int guess = ...
char guessChar = (char)guess + 'a';
if (guessChar == targetLetter) { 
    System.out.println("Correct!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Guess again!")
}
```

Comment: The user has to enter a letter when they are guessing... I have displayed my code for the numbered version of the game! Just to show what i have done

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it in this approach :

1- Create a String `alphabet` with the characters that you want.

2- declare the size of alphabet as `n` variable which will control the random generator range.

3- `alphabet.charAt(random.nextInt(n))` is a random char from the alphabet.

program code will be :

```
String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

int n = alphabet.length();

Random r = new Random();  

System.out.println(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(n)));
```

hope will help solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Once implemented this didnt work as each letter has to be related to an integer and tell the user if they are above the letter or below the letter! However this did help

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Picnic1 {
    // RULE 0: This code is provided as a working example.
    // This rule tests for whether a word starts with the letter 'b' (allowed to the picnic).
    public static boolean rule0(char[] array) {
        if (array[0] == 'b') {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

        // itemMessage:
        // Return message about whether a particular item is allowed to the picnic.
        public static String item ( double[] a){
            // This code works, providing output like these examples:
            //   "banana: true"
            //   "collie: false"
            // It needs to be replaced with a more suitable output.
            // Instead it should return, for example:
            //   "Yes, you can bring a banana to the picnic."
            //   "No, you cannot bring a collie to the picnic."
            if (a[0] == 'b') {
                System.out.println("Yes, you can bring a" + 'a' + "to the picnic");
            }
            else if (a[0] != 'b') {
                System.out.print("No, you can not bring a " + 'a' + "to the picnic");
            }

        }

    }

}
```